# Sample of Single sourcing RAP and RCP? How to run /debug on IDE? How to deploy on tomcat

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, eclipse-rap

I am referring to http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-rcprap/
And created host plug-in and fragment projects RCP and RAP.

How to run them in Eclipse IDE?

How to deploy on tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

Wit the RAP Tools, you can conveniently start a RAP application from the IDE.
The setup is explained in the RAP Developer's Guide, section on [Setting up the Eclipse IDE](https://www.eclipse.org/rap/developers-guide/devguide.php?topic=setup-ide.html&version=2.3).

This Guide also has a section on [WAR deployment](https://www.eclipse.org/rap/developers-guide/devguide.php?topic=deployment.html&version=2.3).